# Moving /setting position of custom tab in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have added a custom tab to a magento 2 store, however I am unable to set the position. I want it between the reviews tab and the description tab.
I am able to add the tab with in the `catalog_product_view.xml` file, but not able to set order.

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to set order. 
When I try to add `after=""` or `before=""` it does not seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

This will add your tab before review tab

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">

<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.tab" as="custom" template="product/view/custom.phtml" group="detailed_info"  before ="review.tab">

<arguments>

<argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>

</arguments>

</block>

</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using this code : -

```
 <referenceBlock name="product.info.details"> 

<block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review" name="custom.tab" as="custom" template="Magento_Review::review.phtml" group="detailed_info" before="reviews.tab">

<block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="product.review.form" >

      <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before"/>

</block>
</block> 
   </referenceBlock>
```

Yes it should be reviews.tab

Let me know if you still face any issues

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help.

Using your block above had no difference on order of tabs.
I did notice an issue with the name of the reviews block. It should be reviews.tab.

I am able to remove the tab with`<referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true" />` so I know that reviews.tab block name is correct.

I also tried moving the reviews.tab using the following:
 `<move element="reviews.tab" destination="product.info.details" after="custom.tab"/>` and that did not work either.

Thanks

Comment: That did not work.

Comment: Here is my block with before reviews tab :

Comment: `<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.tab" as="custom" template="product/view/care_info.phtml" group="detailed_info" before="reviews.tab">
<arguments>
<argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Material Care</argument>
</arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>`

Comment: Just can't get this into the correct position. I can move the reviews block to another part of product page, but cannot make it display after custom tab inside product.info.details block. Kinda weird.

Answer (score 1):

At least in Magento 2.4.4 it's going to be

```
<argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">80</argument>
```

inside your custom tab block, where "80" will define the relative position of a specific tab.

So for example, your complete xml might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">

<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="included_items.tab" as="included_items" template="product/view/included_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info">
<arguments>
<argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Included Items</argument>
<argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">10</argument>
</arguments>
</block>

<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="sizing_chart.tab" as="sizing_chart" template="product/view/sizing_chart_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info">
<arguments>
<argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Sizing Chart</argument>
<argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">50</argument>
</arguments>
</block>

</referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Included Items has index "10" which means it will appear to the left of "Sizing Chart" which has index "50". It's necessary to clean cache after making changes to that xml file.